# Searching Arrays and returning elements within

Tags: java, arrays, search, interface

I have an array named theDirectory, which holds a number of DirectoryEntry's, each of which contain a name, and a telno.
The task I am struggling with is creating a method in a seperate ArrayPhoneDirectory file,  called lookUpEntry, which takes the parameter (String name), and searches through the array, to find the DirectoryEntry that contains that name, and then returns the telno associated with it, using the getNumber method declared in DirectoryEntry.java.

```
    public class DirectoryEntry {
    String name;
    String telno;

    public DirectoryEntry(String name, String telno)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.telno = telno;

    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getNumber()
    {
        return telno;
    }

    public void setNumber(String telno)
    {
        this.telno = telno;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return getClass().getName() + " Name: " + this.name +
                " Number: " + this.telno;
    }

    public String format()
    {
        return String.format("%-20s %-20s", name, telno);
    }

}
```

This is what I have so far, however I think I may be heading down the wrong route, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
public String lookUpEntry(String name)
{
    if (Arrays.asList(theDirectory).contains(name))
    {
        return theDirectory.getNumber;
    }

    else
    {
        return null;
    }

}
```

thanks.

Comment: does `theDirectory` have to be an array? Can it be an `ArrayList` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simpler (and slightly more efficient*) version.

```
public String lookUpEntry(String name){
    for(DirectoryEntry e : theDirectory)
      if(e.getName().equals(name))
        return e.getNumber();
    return null;  //Could not find name
}
```

*Using the for each loop over arrays is faster and also easier to read, in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to the enhanced for loop!

Answer (score 0):

Why you need an array..?? Use HashMap to store the name and number objects like this

```
Map<String, String> entries = new HashMap<>();
entries.put("contact1", "121212");
entries.put("contact2", "22222");
```

When you need to search a contact, use the method

```
entries.get("contact2")
```

Comment: Our assignment is array and interface based, to try and get our heads around the use of arrays, and search and sort functions

Answer (score 0):

Are you required to put these in two different classes. It would be slightly easier to keep them together.
Otherwise I don't really see an issue with your code, except for the fact that I dont see where the array is made or where you reference the other class.
But you are headed down the correct path. Not the most optimal way, but it will def work.
With coding there are always many ways to do things. Not a single right way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the assignment we are required to put them in separate classes as we are focusing on using interfaces. Regarding the lookUpEntry method, we have been told to use the getNumber method declared in DirectoryEntry to return the telno, which I cannot work out how to do, and so have just put return name;. is there anyway of using my getNumber method in this return statement? The array is made in ArrayPhoneDirectory using  private DirectoryEntry[] theDirectory = new DirectoryEntry[capacity];

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
public String lookUpEntry(String name)
{
            List<DirectoryEntry> dirList=Arrays.asList(theDirectory);
            int i=0;
            for( i=0;i<dirList.size();i++){
                if(dirList.get(i).getName().equals(name)){
                    return dirList.get(i).getNumber;
                }
            }

      return null;
}
```

Comment: Your code will not compile (add a return statement at the end) and the last if is not needed among other things.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work great, and more importantly i understand it!